# Update a column in Table B with multiple row values from Table A using XML PATH

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-xml-path

I have 4 columns in Table A viz., Inv_Num1, Inv_Date1, Inv_Amt1, Inv_DocNum1

I have 4 columns in Table B viz., Inv_Num2, Inv_Date2, Inv_Amt2, Inv_Status2

I would like to match the rows between Table A and Table B by using an inner join where condition on is

```
Invoice_Num1=Invoice_Num2  AND Invoice_Date1=Invoice_Date2  AND
Invoice_Amt1=Invoice_Amt2
```

When I do this matching I may get more than 1 row as a result in Table

```
A (Invoice_DocNum1 column)
```

I tried XML Path code but I dont know how to implement in Update statement

```
update cis2
set cis2.Inv_Status2 = 
(SELECT     
    TypeName = STUFF((
        SELECT '; ' + imd1.Inv_DocNum1
        FROM [VRS].[Table_B] cis1
        INNER JOIN [Table_A] imd1 
            ON cis1.Inv_Num1 = imd1.Inv_Num2
        WHERE cis1.Inv_Num1 = imd1.Inv_Num2
        AND cis1.Inv_Date1 = imd1.Inv_Date2
        AND cis1.Inv_Amt1 = imd1.Inv_Amt2

        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
) FROM  Table_B cis2
```

[image: I have explained about Table A and Table B structure and expected output]

Comment: Why oh why do you want to do this? You have nicely normalized data and you are trying to ruin that by slamming delimited data into a single tuple. This violates 1NF.

Comment: But how can i update Inv_Status2 column with the required data? is there any alternate way of doing it?

Please note that i am using a stored procedure to update the some general values in Inv_Status2.

But i would also like to show Inv_Status2 column as shown in expected output.

Comment: Why is this required? I think you are missing the point. This isn't simple because what you are doing is not how relational data works. You would need to first capture the delimited menace you are creating in a cte or similar. Then use that to update your table.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, Can you please help me with an example ?


`WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT DISTINCT Inv_Num1,Inv_DocNum1  = STUFF((SELECT ';'+ LTRIM(STR(Invoice_DocNum))
FROM TableA imd 
WHERE imd.Invoice_Number = imd1.Invoice_Number         
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(max)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM TableA AS imd1  
)
UPDATE cis
SET cis.Inv_Status2=b.Invoice_DocNumber1 
FROM TableB AS cis 
INNER JOIN CTE AS b
ON cis.Inv_Num2 = b.Inv_Num1`


I tried something like above also, not sure whether it is correct :(

Comment: Try looking at the example I posted already. Then ask yourself how you are going to use that column. What happens when you need to update it? What happens when you need to search it?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this to your database is against good practices since it violates 1NF. But you could still this if you are deadset on doing it. Something along these lines should work.

```
with myCte as
(
    SELECT Inv_Num1
        , TypeName = STUFF((
            SELECT '; ' + imd1.Inv_DocNum1
            FROM [VRS].[Table_B] cis1
            INNER JOIN [Table_A] imd1 
                ON cis1.Inv_Num1 = imd1.Inv_Num2
            WHERE cis1.Inv_Num1 = imd1.Inv_Num2
            AND cis1.Inv_Date1 = imd1.Inv_Date2
            AND cis1.Inv_Amt1 = imd1.Inv_Amt2
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
    from Table_A
    group by Inv_Num1
)

update tb
set Inv_Status2 = c.TypeName
from Table_B tb
join myCte c on c.Inv_Num1 = tb.Inv_Num2
```

Comment: I am sorry, its not giving the expected output.

Its gives output like 


a123, b123, a456, b456, a789, b789, c789 for all the line items in TableB (Inv_Status2 column)

Comment: If this is not producing the output you desired it it time for you to post some sample data. Not as pictures, but as text so others can copy and paste it to test their solution. But look closely at your query. You have where predicates that require matching on columns like Amount, but in your sample it looks like those values are not consistent across your "groups".

Answer (score 0):

The answer has two parts. First, you need to produce your comma-separated list per row. The best way to do it is STRING_AGG (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

You will need to use it with the `group by`, like `select ..., STRING_AGG(Inv_DocNum1, ',') group by ...` where `...` stands for your three fields forming unique key.

Second, you need to use `update ... from` syntax, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#l-specifying-a-table-alias-as-the-target-object. In your case, it will be `from` your target table joining the resultset you computed at step one.